# SQL - Combined Group By

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, group-by, left-join

Trying to figure out how to combine these two queries, but am struggling with it.

1.

```
select ia.name, count(archived_i) from (
    select * from incident i
    where i.archived = true
) as archived_i
right join incident_action ia on archived_i.incident_action_id = ia.id
group by ia.name
order by ia.name;
```

yields

```
Detention   3
Expulsion   0
Warning     2
```

2.

```
select in_s.name, count(archived_i) from (
    select * from incident i
    where i.archived = true
) as archived_i
right join incident_severity as in_s on archived_i.incident_severity_id = in_s.id
group by in_s.name
order by in_s.name;
```

yields

```
High    0
Low     5
```

I wanna combine these to form something that yields

```
Detention   High   0
Detention   Low    3
Expulsion   High   0
Expulsion   Low    0
Warning     High   0
Warning     Low    2
```

What would be the correct, performant way to do this?

Comment: A `CROSS JOIN`?

Comment: @TheImpaler in what way, specifically? I tried cross joining, but was getting duplicated counts. I want to spread the count across all 6 combinations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `cross join` referential tables severity and action to generate all possible combinations, and then bring the incident table with a `left join`.The final step is aggregation.

```
select ina.name action, ins.name severity, count(i.archived_i)
from incident_severity ins
cross join incident_action ina
left join incident i 
    on  i.incident_action_id = ina.id
    and i.incident_severity_id = ins.id
    and i.archived
group by ina.name, ins.name
```

Comment: would I index on i.archived, or would it be beneficial to index on multiple columns?

Comment: @jkossis: for performance with this query, you want a multi-column index on `incident(incident_action_id, incident_severity_id, archived)`.

Answer (score 0):

Without changing your queries, you can do a cross join. For example:

```
select
  x.name,
  y.name,
  'x'
from (
  select ia.name, count(archived_i) from (
    select * from incident i
    where i.archived = true
  ) as archived_i
  right join incident_action ia on archived_i.incident_action_id = ia.id
  group by ia.name
  order by ia.name
) x
cross join (
  select in_s.name, count(archived_i) from (
    select * from incident i
    where i.archived = true
  ) as archived_i
  right join incident_severity as in_s 
    on archived_i.incident_severity_id = in_s.id
  group by in_s.name
  order by in_s.name
) y
```

Comment: I don't literally want the 'x' character. I am looking for the count that adds up to 5 to be spread across those combinations.

Comment: @TheImapler I am sorry, I was trying to convey that those numbers were unknown, and the ones I wanted to retrieve. Updated the question.